# Listen message queue SQS with Spring Boot not works with standard config

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, spring-messaging, spring-cloud-aws

I'm unable to make works queue listener with Spring Boot and SQS
(the message is sent and appear in SQS ui)

The `@MessageMapping` or `@SqsListener` not works

Java: 11
Spring Boot: 2.1.7
Dependencie: spring-cloud-aws-messaging

This is my config

```
@Configuration
@EnableSqs
public class SqsConfig {

    @Value("#{'${env.name:DEV}'}")
    private String envName;

    @Value("${cloud.aws.region.static}")
    private String region;

    @Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.access-key}")
    private String awsAccessKey;

    @Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.secret-key}")
    private String awsSecretKey;

    @Bean
    public Headers headers() {
        return new Headers();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageQueue queueMessagingSqs(Headers headers,
                                          QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate) {
        Sqs queue = new Sqs();
        queue.setQueueMessagingTemplate(queueMessagingTemplate);
        queue.setHeaders(headers);
        return queue;
    }

    private ResourceIdResolver getResourceIdResolver() {
        return queueName -> envName + "-" + queueName;
    }

    @Bean
    public DestinationResolver destinationResolver(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync) {
        DynamicQueueUrlDestinationResolver destinationResolver = new DynamicQueueUrlDestinationResolver(
                amazonSQSAsync,
                getResourceIdResolver());
        destinationResolver.setAutoCreate(true);
        return destinationResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync,
                                                         DestinationResolver destinationResolver) {
        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQSAsync, destinationResolver, null);
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory() {
        QueueMessageHandlerFactory factory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        messageConverter.setStrictContentTypeMatch(false);
        factory.setArgumentResolvers(Collections.singletonList(new PayloadArgumentResolver(messageConverter)));
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs);
        factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
        factory.setWaitTimeOut(2);
        return factory;
    }

}
```

I notice also that `org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory` and `org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.annotation.SqsConfiguration` run on startup

And my test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ListenTest {

    @Autowired
    private MessageQueue queue;

    private final String queueName = "test-queue-receive";

    private String result = null;

    @Test
    public void test_listen() {
        // given
        String data = "abc";

        // when
        queue.send(queueName, data).join();

        // then
        Awaitility.await()
                .atMost(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .until(() -> Objects.nonNull(result));

        Assertions.assertThat(result).equals(data);
    }

    @MessageMapping(value = queueName)
    public void receive(String data) {
        this.result = data;
    }
}
```

Do you think something is wrong ?

I create a repo for exemple : (https://github.com/mmaryo/java-sqs-test)
In test folder, change aws credentials in 'application.yml'
Then run tests

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work". What specifically does happen? Is there an error message anywhere, or a message in an SQS error queue?

Comment: Message in SQS queue stay in queue, and receive() method never runs. It seems `@MessageMapping(value = queueName)` not listen to queue ?

Comment: I'm not certain about this tooling. I've only used `@SqsListener`.

Comment: @SqsListener not works too :/

Comment: In QueueMessageHandler `SqsListener sqsListenerAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method,
    SqsListener.class);` always empty. So Spring dot not scan @Sqs in @SpringBootTest and do not scan also in @Compent

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue when using the spring-cloud-aws-messaging package, but then I used the queue URL in the @SqsListener annotation instead of the queue name and it worked.

```
@SqsListener(value = { "https://full-queue-URL" }, deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
public void receive(String message) {
     // do something
}
```

It seems you can use the queue name when using the spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging package. I believe there is some configuration that allows usage of the queue name instead of URL if you don't want to use the starter package.

**EDIT:** I noticed the region was being defaulted to us-west-2 despite me listing us-east-1 in my properties file. Then I created a RegionProvider bean and set the region to us-east-1 in there and now when I use the queue name in the @SqsMessaging it is found and correctly resolved to the URL in the framework code.

Comment: can you post the snippet for the RegionProvider @Bean method?

Comment: @heug `@Bean
    public RegionProvider regionProvider() {
        return () -> Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(queueRegion));
    }
`

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to leverage the @Primary annotation, this is what worked for me:

```
@Autowired(required = false)
private AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider;

@Autowired
private AppConfig appConfig;

@Bean
public QueueMessagingTemplate getQueueMessagingTemplate() {
    return new QueueMessagingTemplate(sqsClient());
}

@Primary
@Bean
public AmazonSQSAsync sqsClient() {
    AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder builder = AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard();

    if (this.awsCredentialsProvider != null) {
        builder.withCredentials(this.awsCredentialsProvider);
    }

    if (appConfig.getSqsRegion() != null) {
        builder.withRegion(appConfig.getSqsRegion());
    } else {
        builder.withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION);
    }

    return builder.build();
}
```

build.gradle needs these deps:

```
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:2.2.0.RELEASE")
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-messaging:2.2.0.RELEASE")
```

Comment: what is AppConfig?

Comment: @EvanGertis a reference to a bean that holds env variables